# LibGDX change screen after 2 seconds

Tags: libgdx

Ive tried using a timer in the render method but that just crashes my game, so how do I change screens after a certain amount of time after rendering.

Comment: You could have a counter accumulating the elapsed time and when that is greater than or equal to two seconds you change the screen.

Comment: @bornander can you gave an example of how to do that im a bit of a newbie

Answer (score 5):

Track the elapsed time in your `Screen`, then when a limit is reach as the `Game` instance to swap to your next screen;

```
public class MyScreen extends ScreenAdapter {    
  private final Game game;
  private float elapsed;

  public MyScreen(final Game game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  public void render(float delta) {
    elapsed += delta;

    // Render or do whatever you do here

    if (elapsed > 2.0) {
      game.setScreen(new MyOtherScreen(game));
    }
  }
}
```

For this I am assuming you're using 
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.html and http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html.